# IOT vs Heap in Oracle. Help me make choice

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I've read many information about IOT, and now in my head gruel...
Pls, help me solve question.

Have table, that have structure:

```
ID (PK); ID_DRUG_NAME (a); ID_FROM (b); ID_PROVIDER (c); DELETED;
```

The data from this table is never deleted but only marked that are removed.
Many queries uses `ID`, another queries uses  `a,b` or `a,c` or `a,b,c`.
I want recreate this table using operator `ORGANIZATION INDEX`.

1. How it will be profitable?
2. How to rightly create a primary key and indexes?
3. What pitfalls do I get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Index-organized tables (IOT) are best used when there is a single access-path. You've identified two different lead columns, so an IOT is probably not a good choice.

The issue here is that, if you make it an IOT, you have to choose one of the two columns (ID  or ID_DRUG_NAME) that you'll frequently be filtering on to index. Theoretically, you could still add a second index on an IOT, but it's almost always a bad idea.  An IOT with a second index is typically performs worse than if the second index doesn't exist, even when querying against the column in the second index.

Comment: +1 Even though you should have written "an IOT is definitely a bad choice" in this case

Comment: Thx, your answer is convincing.